# How is "scuola" pronounced?

Tags: nouns, pronunciation

One source pronounces scuola as "sk'WOH-lah," and another says "sk'WAH-la".

Which one is it, or are there differing dialects in Italian for scuola? Grazie!

Comment: What you mean is whether (and possibly where) the pronunciation of _scuola_ is [/'skwoːla/ or /'skwɔːla/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_phonology). I believe the standard pronunciation is the second one, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: My Zingarelli dictionary reports /'skwɔːla/. Even in ditionaries without [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), /o/ and /ɔ/ are usually told apart as ó and ò, at least on stressed sillables - in this case it is _scuòla_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://it.forvo.com/word/scuola/
BakaSara, lad5450:  /'skwɔːla/
DelidiC, sales: /'skwoːla/
How close or open the 'o' is depends on local accent.
Standard pronunciation is /'skwɔːla/, as can be heard here (first audio): http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=12292&r=932

Answer (score 4):

In Italian “u” can only be pronounced either “oo” (IPA /u/) or, in diphthongs as this one, something like “w” (IPA /w/).

As for the “o”, it is only ever pronounced as a closed or open “o” (IPA /o/ or /ɔ/); here it is /ɔ/.
No way it can be pronounced “a”; where did you find it?

Comment: I guess that WAH in sk'WAH-la is to be pronounced the English way, /'wɔː/

Comment: But then how is _squalo_ to be rendered in English? Maybe you are right...

Comment: @WalterTross: I see your point: it may well be a not too successfull attempt to describe an /ɔ/. I wonder.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with IPA. I'm only sounding it out as if I'm speaking. In English, I believe I hear something like this from Italian speakers: "Sk'wah-la," but in my Italian book it is pronounced phonetically "sk'woah-la". So, it seems that I'm hearing two ways.